# Stuck In Expression Trees

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I am trying to understand this example and I keep failing.

This is the code:

```
// Creating a parameter expression.
ParameterExpression value = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "value");

// Creating an expression to hold a local variable. 
ParameterExpression result = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "result");

// Creating a label to jump to from a loop.
LabelTarget label = Expression.Label(typeof(int));

// Creating a method body.
BlockExpression block = Expression.Block(
    // Adding a local variable. 
    new[] { result },
    // Assigning a constant to a local variable: result = 1
    Expression.Assign(result, Expression.Constant(1)),
    // Adding a loop.
        Expression.Loop(
    // Adding a conditional block into the loop.
           Expression.IfThenElse(
    // Condition: value > 1
               Expression.GreaterThan(value, Expression.Constant(1)),
    // If true: result *= value --
               Expression.MultiplyAssign(result,
                   Expression.PostDecrementAssign(value)),
    // If false, exit the loop and go to the label.
               Expression.Break(label, result)
           ),
    // Label to jump to.
       label
    )
);
```

I know partially what is going on but that label is confusing me so my questions are what is a label and how is that local value begin assigned and used in first item of the block?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation of the methods in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A label identifies a loop. I can understand your confusion, since C# doesn't actually have loop labels, but .NET does use them internally and they are therefore used in .NET's expression trees. Here's some example Java code (which does have loop labels):

```
outerLoop: // This is a label for the outer loop
while (true) {
    innerLoop: // This is a label for the inner loop
    while (true) {
        // Rather than exiting the inner loop (which is what a plain break would
        // do), this exits the outer loop
        break outerLoop;
    }
}
```

The `Expression.Loop` method takes a label as an argument, which says "this label refers to this loop". When you have `Expression.Break(label, result)`, it says "break out of the loop that this label refers to", which in this case is the block's single loop.

For the local variable, `Expression.Block`'s first argument declares all the local variables scoped to that block. So `result` is first declared, then initialized by the `Expression.Assign` call.

The resulting expression tree is approximately equivalent to this C# code:

```
{                      // Expression.Block(
    int result;        //   new[] { result },
    result = 1;        //   Expression.Assign(result, Expression.Constant(1)),
    while (true)       //   Expression.Loop(
    {                  
        if (value > 1) //     Expression.IfThenElse(
        {              //       Expression.GreaterThan(value, Expression.Constant(1)),
            result *=  //       Expression.MultiplyAssign(result,
              value--; //       Expression.PostDecrementAssign(value)),
        }
        else             
        {
            break;     //       Expression.Break(label, result)
        }              //     ),
    }                  //   label)
}                      // )
```

Comment: How can access first argument then and set a value on it inside block?

Comment: The argument isn't accessed first; it's *declared* first, then initialized. I've edited the answer to clarify.

Comment: What do you mean declares? How?

Comment: I've added a code sample. Look at the declaration "int result;".

Comment: I am slowly getting it there. How would the block look alike if I would add eac result to a list and in the end return that list back?